# Mac OS Mojave : finder doesn't show files

Tags: macos, finder

I have a strange behavious of the finder since I have he last mac os : finder doesn't see recently created files.
I am wondering either it can be linked with softwares like oneDrive or GoogleDrive which are linked with the directories on which this happens.

For example on the image here below the finder window lists 2 documents, while a terminal list 4 docs. I know there are 4 docs.

Does anyone have the same issue ?

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific: Is this affecting only specific directories? If so, which ones?

Comment: I think it is affecting the directories wich are under OneDrive and GoogleDrive supervision . At least it is where I saw it happening. It is also new since the update   of OS. Didn't have any issue with the old OS.

Comment: It would be good to know whether the issue is reproducible. If you *think* it is affecting these directories, that it's not enough to really troubleshoot further. I would be suprised if it affected both OneDrive and Google Drive. Have you made sure to update these applications? Does `chflags nohidden /path/to/file` make it appear?

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Mojave, 10.14.4) the problem was iCloud, disabling the iCloud Drive and the Photos backup in `System Preferences > iCloud` worked for me.